# Java JNI: This operation is only valid in the context of an app container

Tags: java, windows, java-native-interface

After failing to get JNI stuff working on the Mac, I decided to try on windows. I compiled my DLL, and put it in the `java.library.path`, just as I did on the Mac.

Now.. Java gives me this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\path\to\dll\TheDll.dll: This operation is only valid in the context of an app container
```

> This operation is only valid in the context of an app container

What? I've tried googling this, but nothing of relevance shows up. Weirdly, it worked on the Mac just fine.

What's the cause of this?

Comment: You need to give us more information. What method is being called? What did not work on the Mac? What *DID* work on the Mac? How are you running the app?

Comment: @maba The method is `SDLMain.init()` and it successfully called that method on the Mac, but the contents of the method didn't. On windows just calling the method throws this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out the error message was generated by Windows, and was caused by this bit of wackiness:

I was compiling as a Windows Store DLL rather than a Win32 DLL. Ridiculous, but at least I found the answer.

Comment: I have the same error for a DLL. I have created a Windows Store DLL project, now I would like to change it to a Win32 DLL but I can't find the compiler/linker options I need to change in Visual Studio 2012.
Can you help me ? Thanks

Comment: @MaximeViargues I just started a "new Win32 project", and in the setup wizard you select the DLL option. Sorry, I don't know how to convert an existing Windows Store DLL to Win32, but if all else fails you could just make a new project and copy the code. Sorry if I wasn't of any help.

Comment: Thank you, I had exactly the same issue.